# Apply a function to a range of cells in a spreadsheet

Tags: grouping, spreadsheet, cells, libreoffice-calc

The answers in topics with similar titles haven't given me much of a resolution to my particular problem, but possibly I am not asking the right question. It might help knowing I'm an absolute noob when it comes to spreadsheets, so finding my way around is next to nil.

Currently I can set a basic function in the first cell A1 `=ROW()`

Simple right? Well now here comes the complication. If I click on the bottom right of the cell and start dragging I can then apply that very same function to a whole range of cells. Let's say I apply it from A1:A10. Every cell within this group now has the same function.

Hooray! We did it, right? I applied a function to a range of cells each with their own output. But wait, if I then go back to the original cell and change its formula none of the other cells change with it. GRRRRR!!!!

There are a couple of fixes I've come up with but don't necessarily know how to implement. The first is to have every cell link back to the original cell and reference its function. This would be useful if I wanted to randomly scatter dependent cells about the document. The other would be much more useful in an orderly group where you know the exact dimensions by specifying in the original cell the size of the array you want to apply the function to.

With that said, let me hear your thoughts.

---

The closest I've come to an answer is to use `FORMULA()` which returns the formula used by a cell as text. Unfortunately all answers on evaluating the text resort to scripting. How strange! I thought something like this would be common. Might as well get to scripting.

---

Hold on, I may have spoke too soon. An array can be made with `=MUNIT()`, but it's only square. Drats!

---

Ok... I'm hoping the zebra stripes will eventually become its own answer unless someone else beats me to it. So a simple array can be made with `={1,2;3,4}` where commas separate values by column and semicolons for values by row except to generate it you have to press <kbd>Control+Shift+Enter</kbd> (because reasons?). I'm thinking now that I'll need to have functions that can generate lists of values based on a single function for each row, and pray that it'll work. So, back to looking. (Wow this is taking forever)

---

The way I was hypothesizing can't even generate a 1x1, e.g., `={ROW()}` returns `Err:512` which is a formula overflow.

---

Alright, in summary so far I've narrowed down the two options,

```
1) link every cell to the original formula
2) populate an array with a single formula
```

each with their own incomplete answer,

```
a) use FORMULA() to return the formula of a cell as text
b) create a hypothetical array like so ={LIST_OF_VALUES()}
```

These both require a strange form of the nonexistent `EVALUATE()` function to 'function' correctly. Isn't that fun?

---

Google Sheets handles case b by allowing `={ROW()}`<kbd>Control+Shift+Enter</kbd> to generate `=ArrayFormula({ROW()})`. Working with the general case of any sized array being filled with a single function doesn't exist in the world of spreadsheets it seems. That's very saddening because I can't think of a much better tool for what I want to do. Copy paste it is until I need to use macros.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Excel? Google Sheets? Apple Numbers?

Comment: LibreOffice Calc but I was hoping for a generic solution.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/q/906861/84724 ...

Comment: @tohuwawohu It looks like macros might be the way to go. I didn't know you could save them to individual files. I also liked your method of delegation through a global variable, although it only works for a few special cases. It's upsetting how the functionality for arrays is so lackluster especially because it's so common in most if not all data manipulation. They must assume if you're doing that type of stuff you'll be scripting anyway. Even then I'm quite surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could write some complex code to update functions, but wouldn't the easy way be just to drag it to the same range of cells the same way you did before? It should properly overwrite the existing code in there, and if it doesn't, you can just as easily delete the outdated code and drag the new code in.

Comment: Complex answers are what I was referring to in the first sentence, and are exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid. Like you're saying I can repeat the steps in paragraph 3 to reproduce the effects but it's rather laborious and ugly to do, don't you think? To me I imagine this functionality as a simple operation that should have some form of native support.

Comment: "It's rather laborious and ugly" It's two clicks.

Comment: Yeah two clicks is easy (and gets the job done). The problem though is that each cell is still treated as an individual. With increasing complexity it seems like it'd eventually get out of hand, but maybe not, I don't have the experience to say. Still, even if two clicks is easy, I find treating the group of cells as its own unit much easier and I would like the document to reflect the same.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your specific use case, creating a [user-defined function](https://help.libreoffice.org/4.0/Calc/User-Defined_Functions) may help:

- use the Basic IDE to create your function;
- apply it to any cells on any sheet;
- modifying the Basic code will affect all cells where the function is used.

I've elaborated the steps in an [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/906962/84724).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach is to simply drag the amended formula over the range of cells (as advised by OldBunny2800). This is less error prone and easier to maintain than a custom macro.

Another option would be to use an [array function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions). Then you only have to edit the function once, and the same edit will be automatically applied to the whole range of cells in that array function.